# Error: there is no unique constraint in the referenced table "table_name" that matches the specified keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ingredients 
(
    i_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    i_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dishes 
(
    d_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    d_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dishes_ingredients 
(
    di_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    di_d_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES dishes(d_id),
    di_i_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES ingredients(i_id),
    di_i_weight DECIMAL NOT NULL
);
```

I get the error:

> "there is no unique constraint in the referenced table
> "dishes_ingredients" that matches the specified keys".

I have searched for this problem and notice that my two foreign keys in table "dishes_ingredients" are referencing two serial primary keys from tables "ingredients" and "dishes", and thus, they are by definition unique. What I am doing wrong?

This is the create statement for the table that references the table "dishes_ingredients":

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ratings (
        r_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        r_c_id INTEGER REFERENCES customers(c_id),
        r_d_id INTEGER REFERENCES dishes_ingredients(di_d_id),
        r_value INTEGER NOT NULL    
    );
```

Comment: The error says `... referenced table "dishes_ingredients" ...` so this is coming from another table that is referencing `dishes_ingredients`.

Comment: If any of these tables existed beforehand, you need to inspect those - `if not exists` will ignore your current DDL and the preexisting conditions continue to apply. The error also seems to come from something else that's trying to reference `dishes_ingredients`, not from `dishes_ingredients` trying to reference something else. Am I right to suspect there's more code before or after what you showed, that you did not attach?

Comment: Thanks very much guys. I have found the mistake because your remarks about what was the referenced table.